# ConfigurationManager in WPF

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, configurationmanager, appsettings

I have a config file in a wpf project to store the connectionstring.
But when I try to get AppSettings and ConnectionStrings, I get null.

the WEB.config file is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Trackboard" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Trackboard;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFileName=E:\Users\Sean\Workspace\DATABASE\Trackboard.mdf"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Trackboard" value="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Trackboard;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFileName=E:\Users\Sean\Workspace\DATABASE\Trackboard.mdf"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I tried in several ways:

```
W1: ConnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trackboard"].ConnectionString;
W2: ConnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString;
W3: ConnStr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Trackboard"];
W4: ConnStr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[0];
```

None of them worked.

But this one worked:

```
ConnStr = @"Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Trackboard;Integrated Security=True;AttachDbFileName=E:\Users\Sean\Workspace\DATABASE\Trackboard.mdf";
```

(That means I cannot use a config file, which is against my will)
I need help.

Comment: Why you choose WEB.config for WPF app. It have to the APP.config.

Comment: :P I just renamed it to WEB.config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out!
I shouldn't have created a new config file. There is a default app.config file in the project.
Now everything is fine.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Trackboard.Properties.Settings.TrackboardConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DATABASE\Trackboard.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

```cs
private static string ConnStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trackboard.Properties.Settings.TrackboardConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 14):

Just add an `app.config`  and not `web.config` because it is not a web application.

And after that it's too simple, just add a reference to to System.Configuration and then use this.

```
var ConnStr = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Trackboard"];
```

Answer (score 2):

This one  use `System.Configuration` namespace

```
using System.Configuration;
```

Or add `System.Configuration` in reference

```
System.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Trackboard"].ConnectionString;
System.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[0].ConnectionString;
```

Comment: I did add the System.Configuration reference and namespace. The problem seems to be that System.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings has a count of 0, that's why I can't get the value by key or index.It's weird.It works in winform application.